# BASH: Want to get the size from the Desktop

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm working on a iMac and I'm trying to get the size from the Desktop.

File: /Users/admin/Desktop

I use the following command:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop > temp 2> /dev/null | tail -1 temp
```

When I use this pipe it doesn't work, BUT when I use these 2 commands one after the other it works. Now my question is, does someone know why the pipe doesn't work but these 2 codes one after the other works ?

Comment: You don't need a pipe here, use a semi-colon in its place. What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm working on a little task, where I have to get the size from a few folders and when I use the "du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop" I receive more then one line of output and I only want to get the line with the size of the Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection `> temp` saves the STDOUT in file `temp` (on current directory).

So get rid of the pipe (as STDOUT and STDERR (to `/dev/null`) of `du` are already consumed), and use `tail` directly on the file:

```
tail -1 temp
```

Together, use `;` as command separator:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop >temp 2>/dev/null; tail -1 temp
```

You can use the short circuit operator `&&` to run `tail` only if `du` succeeds:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop >temp 2>/dev/null && tail -1 temp
```

---

Also, you could leave the STDOUT alone, use pipe to pass it to `tail`'s STDIN:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop 2>/dev/null | tail -1 temp
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest option:**

You should simply use the s option:

```
du -hs /Users/admin/Desktop
```

which would give you the sum of the folder you pass as an argument.

**Previous answers:**

This is a bit too complicated for what you are trying to achieve, that is, get the last line of the output of:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop
```

I would pipe this into `sed` like this to get that working (one of many options):

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop | sed -n '$p'
```

And if you absolutely want to use `tail`, this would turn into:

```
du -h -d1 /Users/admin/Desktop | tail -1
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but even when I use your solution, I still don't get only one line as output.